# AC_CHECK_FUNCS doesn't find shm_open

Tags: gcc, configuration, linker, ghc, configure

I'm having trouble building a project that attempts to check for the presence of `shm_open` and `shm_unlink`.  The relevant lines of configure.ac are:

```
# Avoid adding rt if absent or unneeded
AC_CHECK_LIB(rt, shm_open, [EXTRA_LIBS="$EXTRA_LIBS rt" CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -lrt"])

# needs -lrt on linux
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([shm_open shm_unlink])
```

The `AC_CHECK_LIB` line succeeds, however `AC_CHECK_FUNCS` fails for both.  Looking in `config.log`, I see

```
configure:4133: checking for shm_open in -lrt
configure:4158: /usr/bin/gcc -o conftest  -fno-stack-protector         -Wl,--hash-size=31 -Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads   conftest.c -lrt   >&5
configure:4158: $? = 0
configure:4167: result: yes
configure:4178: checking for shm_open
configure:4178: /usr/bin/gcc -o conftest  -fno-stack-protector    -lrt      -Wl,--hash-size=31 -Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads   conftest.c  >&5
/tmp/ccg0yu56.o: In function `main':
conftest.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `shm_open'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It appears that the only difference between the two checks is the position of the `-lrt` argument.  When I try running gcc on a simple file manually, I get the same behavior, i.e. linking succeeds only when `-lrt` comes after the source file input.

So, what do I need to do so `configure` will determine that `shm_open` and `shm_unlink` exist?  I suspect this is something particular to my system, as the project I'm configuring is pretty widely used (the `unix` package bundled with the ghc compiler), and it used to work (when I built this package on a different system with gcc-4.4.5, it worked, however that environment is no longer available).  My preferred solution would be either a change to the system/environment or some combination of flags to configure, however if there's a standard modification for `configure.ac` that I could send upstream, that's acceptable also.

I've tried various combinations of CFLAGS and LDFLAGS, but the `-lrt` flag always appears before the input file, so the check still fails.

My system is Ubuntu 12.04 (precise)

```
$gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
$ uname -a
Linux hostname 3.2.0-26-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 17:49:24 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks!

Comment: For now, I can solve this by configuring with LIBS=-lrt.  Leaving the question open for now hoping that a better solution will come along.

Comment: Hackish suggestion: `-Wl,--no-as-needed` (iirc) in `CFLAGS`?

Answer (score 0):

Macro have full form:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB (library, function, [action-if-found], [action-if-not-found], [other-libraries])
```

Please note `other-libraries`. This option is useful specifically for cases you described -- to pass `-lm`, `-lrt` and other common guys to avoid unresolved references in linker ordering.

Check doc page for more information on [AC_CHECK_LIB](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Libraries.html) macro

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this is insufficient.  `AC_CHECK_LIB` works because it's testing for librt.  The following call to `AC_CHECK_FUNCS` then fails.  It gets called with `-lrt`, but the flag is too early.